# Generating field value on object initialization through annotation

Tags: java, annotations

Good day!

I am currently writing a library that basically just generates values calculated with a custom algorithm. These serve as IDs. We are using that library across several projects within our internal ecosystem, so it should be as independent as possible.

For convenience, I now would like to add a functionality similar to the `@GeneratedValue` annotation of JPA.

See the following example code:

```
public class Foo {

    @MyAnnotation
    private String id;

    public Foo() {}

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

For this scenario, I want the field `id` to automatically be filled with a new ID as provided by the utility method inside my library, as soon as the object is being initialized.

How can I achieve that in a way, that the project utilizing the library has minimum effort to implement it?

Comment: Make your class's generation be static or singleton, and have clients do `private String id = MyClass.getId();` maybe?

Comment: That is already the case. My question really just aims for an annotation based solution. Just as a "fancy alternative" and for me to learn a bit more about the whole annotation system.